# How do I sort multiple fields in a collection using the Comparator?

Tags: java, sql, database, comparator

I have this query for which I have written a DAL for that basically runs a search criteria and if found, adds it to a list. But the problem I am having is to sort the list based on the fields.

For example,

```
     select * from HELLO.TABLE Where total=? and max = ?
   ORDER BY FRLevel DESC, TransferLevel DESC, PriorLimitsLevel DESC
```

How do I use a comparator to sort these fields. Here is my Java Code,

```
public List<PgmTierCriteriaVO> getCriteriaListForAL(DriverVO driverVO,
        String productType, PolicyVersionVO policyVersionVO, String rateDate)
        throws Exception {

    String pgmCode = driverVO.getPgmCode().trim();
    String versionType = policyVersionVO.getVersionType().trim();
    String pgmCodeShort = pgmCode.substring(0, 5);

    PgmTierCriteriaID pgmTierCriteriaID = new PgmTierCriteriaID();
    pgmTierCriteriaID.setPgmCode(pgmCode);
    List<PgmTierCriteriaVO> pgmCriteriaVOList = pgmPayPlanService
            .getPgmTierCriteriaList(pgmTierCriteriaID);
    List<PgmTierCriteriaVO> pgmCriteriaVOListAL = new ArrayList<PgmTierCriteriaVO>();

    if (productType != null && rateDate != null) {
        if (productType.equalsIgnoreCase("PPA")) {

            for (PgmTierCriteriaVO pgmTierCriteriaVO : pgmCriteriaVOList) {
                if (pgmTierCriteriaVO.getAppliesToCode() != null) {

                    if ((StringUtil.getDate(rateDate).after(pgmTierCriteriaVO.getEffDate()) 
                        || StringUtil.getDate(rateDate).equals(pgmTierCriteriaVO.getEffDate()))
                        && StringUtil.getDate(rateDate).before(pgmTierCriteriaVO.getExpDate())
                        && (pgmTierCriteriaVO.getAppliesToCode().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("B") 
                        || pgmTierCriteriaVO.getAppliesToCode().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(versionType))) {
                        pgmCriteriaVOListAL.add(pgmTierCriteriaVO);
                    } else {
                        pgmCriteriaVOListAL = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else if (productType.equalsIgnoreCase("CV")) {

            for (PgmTierCriteriaVO pgmTierCriteriaVO : pgmCriteriaVOList) {
                if (pgmTierCriteriaVO.getAppliesToCode() != null) {

                    if ((StringUtil.getDate(rateDate).after(pgmTierCriteriaVO.getEffDate()) 
                        || StringUtil.getDate(rateDate).equals(pgmTierCriteriaVO.getEffDate()))
                            && StringUtil.getDate(rateDate).before(pgmTierCriteriaVO.getExpDate())
                            && pgmCodeShort.equalsIgnoreCase(pgmTierCriteriaVO.getPgmCode().substring(0, 5))
                            && (pgmTierCriteriaVO.getAppliesToCode().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("B") 
                            || pgmTierCriteriaVO.getAppliesToCode().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(versionType))) {
                        pgmCriteriaVOListAL.add(pgmTierCriteriaVO);
                    } else {
                        pgmCriteriaVOListAL = null;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return pgmCriteriaVOListAL;
}
```

I need to return the sorted list instead of just the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java 8, the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class picked up a number of useful methods to make it easy to create comparators and chain comparisons together with various [thenComparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) options.

If you cannot use java 8, the guava library provides the [Ordering](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class, which provides similar functionality. For example, the [compound](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#compound(java.util.Comparator)) method provides the ability to chain instances much like the thenComparing in java 8.